# C#: MessageBox.Show Error - method but used like a type

Tags: c#, messagebox

So I have the declaration at the beginning of my class file

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

But when I try to issue the statement

```
MessageBox.Show("Pow");
```

I receive the error

```
Error   2   'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window, string)' is a 'method' but is used like a 'type'
```

Complete code:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace Contacts
{
    class AnotherClass
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Pow");
    }   
}
```

I can't seem to find any reason for this.  The other oddity is that when I type MessageBox, Intellisense finds it, but after placing my ( . ) I don't receive the typical menu of method options from that class such as "Show".

Any thoughts?

Comment: What type of project is this? Console, Library, WinForms, other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out nevermind. The principal of Class which can contain methods, properties and field declarations.

Comment: so in the end how did you code it? cuz i have to do manual debugging myself with a messagebox

Answer (score 3):

It's simple really. Main() is the first function which executes in a C++ or C# application. and in your original code you have declared the namespaces, created a class but did not create a function. just used the MessageBox.Show method. In second example, you had created a function which you then put in the method MessageBox.Show and because the function is called Main() it is the first function to execute at the start of the program.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Should have renamed Main() to NotMain() in Program.cs then added code to AnotherClass. The code should look like this.

```
class AnotherClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Pow!);
    }
}
```

Not exactly why but it works... newbie